# bind the path value to image display component in angular

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array, formarray

Here I created dynamic form to Update form value

I have a problem in bind the path of image at pointoIntrest array display component

Model arr.model.ts

```
export interface A{

name:string,



}

export interface section{

  image:string

  pointofIntrest : PointofIntrest[];

} 

export interface  PointofIntrest{
   images:ImagewithAlt[];
  
}



constructor(public http: HttpClient, private fb: FormBuilder){



 this.profile=this.fb.group({

name: ['', Validators.required],


sections: this.fb.array([this.createDestinationSection()])

 })

}

createDestinationSection() {

return this.fb.group({

 city: [''],

pointsOfInterests: 

 this.fb.array([this.createPointsOfInterests()])

  })

}
```

this is the code we patched the value to name and city formControl

here find() is the method we used to get data for particular id value from database

```
this.find(this.id)

  .subscribe((data) => {

 const destinationSection = this.profile.get('sections') as FormArray;

 destinationSection.clear();
 
 data.sections.forEach((item) => {

   item.pointsOfInterests.forEach((b) => {
     const pointsOfInterest = 
     this.arrivalGuideService.newPointOfInterest();

    (section.get('pointsOfInterests') as FormArray).push(
            pointsOfInterest,
          );

     b.images.forEach((i) => {

            const image: FormGroup = this.arrivalGuideService.newImageAlt();

            (pointsOfInterest.get('images') as FormArray).push(
              new FormGroup({
                path: new FormControl(i.path),

                alt: new FormControl(i.alt),

                type: new FormControl(i.type),

              }),

            );

          });
      })
```

})

a.html

```
<div *ngFor="let pointsOfInterest1 of pointsOfInterest(destinationIndex).controls ; let pointsOfInterestsIndex=index">

      <div [formGroupName]="pointsOfInterestsIndex">

         <div *ngFor="let image of images(destinationIndex, pointsOfInterestsIndex).controls; let imageIndex=index">

              <div [formGroupName]="imageIndex">

               <div class="image-wrapper edit-highlight-img mr-2 mb-2 mt-2" >
     
                  <video
     
                    [src]="imagePath+**videoPath**"          
                        
                    heigh="100"
 
                    width="150"
    
                    controls

                  ></video>
               
              </div>

            </div>
      
         </div>

       </div>

     </div>
```

i need to set the path string to videoPath attribute

when we fetch the data  using find method path data comes from back end following format like this

and also i need to bind image path of pointofinterest as well

Comment: Hi, do you mind to update your question and make sure code appears correctly so we can help you

Comment: updates the code